# My python webhook isn't giving me results

Tags: python, json, flask, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I've been working on trying to edit a webhook that was originally meant to be used for a weather API to get to be used with a postcode/zipcode API. The original file is here: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-weather-python/blob/master/app.py
I can't understand where mine is different, I thought I had solved it when I replaced urlencode with quote but alas, it wasn't enough.
The problem is very unlikely to do with the source json request that collects the postcode in postcodeValue(). The api url comes out correct when you enter it into a browser and is presented quite simply. 
https://api.getaddress.io/find/SW11%201th?api-key=I98umgPiu02GEMmHdmfg3w12959
Is it in the correct format? Maybe I need to convert it to become even more JSON then it already is. This question is essentially an end of day brain dump that I I'm hoping that someone can save me with.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from future.standard_library import install_aliases
install_aliases()

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode, quote
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

import json
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

# Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)

#this line is just naming conventions I reckon with a reference to expect to receive data as POST
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

#who knows where this is getting printed
    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

    res = processRequest(req)

    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    # print(res)
    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r


def processRequest(req):

    if req.get("result").get("action") != "yahooWeatherForecast":
        return {}
    baseurl = "https://api.getaddress.io/find/"
    apikey = "?api-key=I98umgPiu02GEMmHdmfg3w12959"
    yql_query = postcodeValue(req)
    if yql_query is None:
        return {}
    #this line is the actual api request    
    yql_url = baseurl + quote(yql_query) + apikey
    result = urlopen(yql_url).read()
    data = json.loads(result)
    res = makeWebhookResult(data)
    return res

    #this function extracts an individual parameter and turns it into a string
def postcodeValue(req):
    result = req.get("result")
    parameters = result.get("parameters")
    postcode = parameters.get("postcode")
    if postcode is None:
        return None

    return postcode

#def housenoValue(req):
  #  result = req.get("result")
    #parameters = result.get("parameters")
    #houseno = parameters.get("houseno")
    #if houseno is None:
      #  return None
    #return houseno

def makeWebhookResult(data):
    longitude = data.get("longitude")
    if longitude is None: 
        return {}

#def makeWebhookResult(data):
#    query = data.get('query')
#    if query is None:
#        return {}

#    result = query.get('results')
#    if result is None:
#        return {}

#    channel = result.get('channel')
#    if channel is None:
#        return {}

#    item = channel.get('item')
#    location = channel.get('location')
#    units = channel.get('units')
#    if (location is None) or (item is None) or (units is None):
#        return {}

#    condition = item.get('condition')
#    if condition is None:
#        return {}

    # print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))

    speech = "Sausage face " + longitude

    print("Response:")
    print(speech)

    return {
        "speech": speech,
        "displayText": speech,
        # "data": data,
        # "contextOut": [],
        "source": "apiai-weather-webhook-sample"
    }

#More flask specific stuff
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print("Starting app on port %d" % port)

    app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Perhaps try printing *before* doing anything else (ie, reading json). It might also help to print the body of the request. Have you tried using wget or similar to send a POST to this webhook?

Comment: Cheers! Alex's local webhook link along with your comment inspired me to download ngrok where I found the problem was that I didn't put str(longitude). I only chose longitude as my placeholder, it didn't even cross my mind that it was a float!! Ngrok is a god send though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit cleaner version of your code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET'])
def webhook():
    res = processRequest()
    return res


def processRequest():
try:
    result = urlopen("https://api.getaddress.io/find/SW11%201th?api-key=I98umgPiu02GEMmHdmfg3w12959").read()
    return result
except:
    return "Error fetching data"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print("Starting app on port %d" % port)

    app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Open your browser and go to http://localhost:5000/webhook and you should see a response.

Comment: Rewriting someone else's code does little to help them understand where the problem is...

Comment: Cheers! You're local webhook link along with shadows comment inspired me to download ngrok where I found the problem was that I didn't put str(longitude). I only chose longitude as my placeholder, it didnt even cross my mind that it was a float!! Thanks a lot, ready to progress again tonight